# is there a word that encompasses both 'schema' and 'data'?

Tags: schema, terminology, class-design

I need a word that covers both schema and data.

I'm designing some classes that are part of a system that needs to store and process data that will only be defined at run time. I have some classes that contain a definition objects, and a storage objects.

This is going into a refactor of a core section a code base that has been going strong for 15 years, lots of people will need to use and understand the source code, so i'd like to do what i can to make it easy to understand. A group of us a have haggled and sweated over the design, but no-one has come up with a name for the classes:

I feel:

```
[Unknown Word]
|
|______schema
|______data
```

is what we are looking for

but

```
data
|
|______schema
|______storage
```

is the best so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about **model**?

You have some **data** which is persisted to the **store** according to a given **schema** (possibly required by the store itself). You create, remove, update or delete data through some **operations**, which present the results in a format useful for manipulation: this format can be the same one defined by the storing schema or an abstraction or anyway a manipulation of it.

I would go with model.

Comment: Model is pretty good, and actually the closest I found a word i was comfortable with, but the system has a lot of functionality around something unrelated called 'models' and so I think I instinctively rejected it. but I think you're correct model is good.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
application
system
solution
etc.
```

or if it has a specific target, can use that, e.g.

```
customers
products
scheduling
etc..
```

Comment: In this case, the class is just a small piece of a big system, so a word like solution, that conveys 'the whole thing' won't be correct. the data and it's purpose isn't known until run time, so a concrete noun for a specific target also a problem.